# Cannot save custom product attribute via custom console command

Tags: product-attribute, custom-attributes, cli, command

I am trying to update a custom product attribute via a custom console command. The command runs, and the product seemingly saves; it never throws an exception or any form of error, yet the attribute is not being saved in the database.

Code from command class

```
foreach ($products as $k => $product) {
            if ($product->getData('price_per_unit')) {
                continue;
            }

            $priceExtVat = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount();
            $unitsPerPack = $product->getData('units_per_pack') ?? 1;
            $pricePerUnit = $priceExtVat / (float) $unitsPerPack;

            try {
                $product->setData('price_per_unit', $pricePerUnit);
                $this->productRepository->save($product);
                $output->writeln("<info>Product PPU Updated! {$key}/{$total}</info>");
            } catch (CouldNotSaveException | InputException | StateException $e) {
                $output->writeln($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, so it would not throw any exception. The only problem here is this code:

```
            if ($product->getData('price_per_unit')) {
                continue;
            }
```

That code skips code below it if the product has attribute named `price_per_unit` and is not empty.

Could you please update your question with the output of the command?

Comment: That part is correct. If that attribute exists and has a value, I want to skip it.

Comment: I got it. Do you see the message `<info>Product PPU Updated! {$key}/{$total}</info>` on each of product where the `price_per_unit` value is meant to be updated?

Comment: Yes, i see the "updated!" message, but the attribute is not entered into the DB, as explained in the post.